# random ConfigurationBuilder behavior

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console-application

In a .net core application, why I am always in "production", even if the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is 'development'?

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        BuildConfig(builder);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();
        // ...

        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                switch (serviceToUse) { // ... } })
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build();

        IService svc;
        // ... got the corresp service...
        svc.Run();
    }

    static void BuildConfig(IConfigurationBuilder builder) {
        string env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")
                                                             ?? "Production";
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true)
            .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables(); 
    }
}
```

However, when I test

[image]

I get rather unexpected values in the test setting:

```
[13:36:55 ERR] Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable('ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT')=Development
[13:36:55 ERR] Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable('DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT')=Development
[13:36:55 ERR] The test setting is 'test value from secrets.json';
```

having this in projet:

[image]

My question is why does it take the `Production` settings if I am in `Development` mode?

Comment: Don't use a one-liner to both read the environment variable, replace it *and* generate the file name. You have no idea what filename was used right now. Extract `{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"` into a separate variable and inspect it.

Comment: What does `appsettings.json` contain?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as you can see from the output, the Env value is "Development", the appsettings.json contains the similar string with the resp. file name...

Comment: Have you looked into Solution Explorer - Project - Right Click - Properties - Debug - Environment Variables?

Comment: I updated the OP, please see if it does answer to your questions

Answer (score 2):

It’s unclear to me where you are retrieving the configuration using `this._config.GetValue<string>("test")`. My guess is that you are retrieving it from the `IConfiguration` injected via DI.

In that case, you should note that the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` will also already come with its own configuration setup which does not really care about what you are doing before with your `BuildConfig`.

The default host builder will already set up configuration using the files `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.<env>.json` (and others) and will register *that* configuration as the `IConfiguration` singleton that is being provided to your application. In order to register the environment-specific file, it will use the environment from the [`IHostEnvironment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostenvironment?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) which is what decides what *actual* environment your application is running on.

With ASP.NET Core and the web host, it is possible to configure this environment using the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. However, since you are *not* using ASP.NET Core but just the host builder on its own, this environment variable is not being used. Instead, the default host builder will look for the environment variable `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`.

Alternatively, you can also call [`hostBuilder.UseEnvironment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.useenvironment?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to set the environment explicitly if you want to take it from a different environment variable.

Finally, when you are setting up your own configuration, I would suggest you to reconfigure your host so that it will use *this* configuration object itself instead of building its own (which may or may not match your desired setup). You can do that by calling [`hostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.configureappconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Comment: the idea is taken from there https://youtu.be/GAOCe-2nXqc?t=1526

Comment: I updated the OP to explain better where from I take the config, is injected, as you said, see updated OP code I will try to understand what should I use in ConfigureAppConfiguration and when should I put it...

Comment: @Serge To be honest, I watched that video you linked to from a previous question you posted, start to finish. I would advise you to not follow that video. It is a poor example and will only confuse you more when you try to do actual production ready code. Go to the documentation and read up on what they have there.

Comment: @Serge Now you have updated your question and it shows that it is reading the value from the user secrets which is to be expected because user secrets overwrite the values in the `appsettings.<env>.json`. Looks to me like it is working exactly as it should.